# How does one specify a particular cipher suite for a nginx docker instance?

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, lets-encrypt, discourse

I am running a newly built `discourse` `docker` image on Google Compute Engine.  I converted that to use https using `letsencrypt` following the [walk through](https://meta.discourse.org/t/setting-up-lets-encrypt/40709) and I get an A+ rating from [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=forum.rebol.info&latest).  However the scripting agent I'm using doesn't support either of the two TLS 1.0 cipher suites enabled [`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`, `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`] and I'd like to add `TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA` which is supported by the open source rebol3 fork ren-c.

I've modified my [web.ssl.template.yml](https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker/blob/master/templates/web.ssl.template.yml#L22) file from

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:\
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:\
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA;
```

to

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:\
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:\
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA;
```

and rebuilt the app using

```
sudo ./launcher rebuild app
```

but this doesn't alter the cipher_suites available.

I'm now wondering if I have to alter the nginx.conf directly, wherever that is, instead of asking the discourse build script to do it ...

Comment: See [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) *(voted to migrate)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the line in `/var/discourse/templates/web.ssl.template.yml`

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:\
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256$RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA;
```

to

```
ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5';
```

changes the supported TLS 1.0 suites to

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35) 256
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x84)    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f) 128
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x41)
```

and still gives an A+ rating from ssllabs.

Answer (score 0):

1. `mkdir -p containers/templates`
2. `cp templates/web.ssl.template.yml containers/templates`
3. fuss with the file
4. add `containers/templates/web.ssl.template.yml` to you `app.yml` file in the `templates` section
5. profit

Comment: The web.ssl.template.yml is already in my app.yml as detailed above.  Adding it again didn't make any difference :(